# Change value of an attribute if the element has a additional attribute with a specific id

Tags: xml, xslt

At first I will shortly describe what I want to do: I´m working with a SysMl modeler to creat an activity diagram. After I finished my model with the SysML modeler I can creat an XML file out of my model. This XML file shall be imported into different tool. However for the better understanding of the source XML code I want to transform it. In the following XML code you can see the 'edge' node. Each 'edge' node refers to a 'target' and 'source'. But if you not much into the code you can´t read out to which element 'source' and 'target' refers (you see only some letters and numbers in a row). 
If you look further you recognize that the letters and rows refers to "real" names like 'machine1'. Now my question: how can I write a code for the transformation that switchs for example 'target="abcd"' to 'target='machine2"'?

I´ve the following XML code:

```
<uml:Model xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20131001"
           xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore"
           xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/UML"
           xmi:id="_x3pzQHiSEemHwJRDr6_Icw"
           name="activity_diagram">
   <Entity name="Activity_diagram">
      <edge xmi:id="_51rDcHrnEemHwJRDr6_Icw"
            target="abcd"
            source="1234"/>
      <edge xmi:id="_C81fcHrsEemj44S3Yi86Ww"
            target="wwww"
            source="abcd"/>
      <edge xmi:id="_Dgu2sHrsEemj44S3Yi86Ww"
            target="zuio"
            source="wwww"/>
      <edge xmi:id="_ECWWAHrsEemj44S3Yi86Ww"
            target="yxcv"
            source="zuio"/>
      <node xmi:id="1234" name="machine1"/>
      <node xmi:id="yxcv" name="machine5"/>
      <node xmi:id="abcd" name="machine2"/>
      <node xmi:id="zuio" name="machine4"/>
      <node xmi:id="wwww" name="machine3"/>
   </Entity>
</uml:Model>
```

[Here is my current code, as you can see I wanted to reduce the complexity of the code that´s why the actual code is a bit different than the one you can see above](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9G/2)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** to lookup the node names - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20131001">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="node-by-id" match="node" use="@xmi:id" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="edge">
    <edge xmi:id="{@xmi:id}"
          target="{key('node-by-id', @target)/@name}"
          source="{key('node-by-id', @source)/@name}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```